# Exponential function / exponential generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could someone explain me the following transition:

$$ (e^t - 1)^n = \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}(-1)^je^{(n-j)t} $$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be closed:

This is an application of the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).